# Nativescript js update

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

The NativeScript manual says:

> NativeScript will automatically compile TypeScript (.ts) files to
>   JavaScript when the project is built.

However in my angular + typescript mobile app i have noticed that occasionally the compilation of *.ts* to the *.js* files doesn't work as i see both files are not the same. For example if I update the `app-routing.module.ts` or `app.module.ts` their `.js` files are not getting updated causing multiple errors, until I manually update them. The question I have is there a command which can force the compilation of *.ts* to the *.js* files?

My configuration is Win10 + Android + NS 3.4.1

**Update**: As always, short after the posting the question i found that using the `tsc [filename]` compiles to the relevant js file. Unfortunately, i do see a lot of errors which i am investigating.

Comment: Your issue seems to be solved. If this is the case please answer your question by yourself instead of updating your question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution rather good practice. When working with NS always do often backups. My issue were caused by bad ts format which wouldn't allow the compilation of ts to js. So, if you notice this happening with your application revert to the last known good state and find the issue step by step.